# How to create UI like spotify's Equalizer UI in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, spotify, uislider

Hello i'm iOS fresher & don't have so much idea about creating complex UI, i want to create equalizer UI like spotify's equalizer UI. currently i had setup my equalizer using UISlider. What should i use to modify my UI like spotify'S EQ UI. It will be nice if you can help with Example code.
Thank you.

---

[This is my EQ UI.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsIK8.png)

[This is what i want to create. EQ UI of spotify.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mc07.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach could be simple:

- Make the color of your sliders gauges clear so they are transparent
- Read the values of your sliders and draw lines between them
- Create a polygon with the coordinates of your sliders values + the two points at the bottom and fill it with a color gradient

As your sliders are equally spaced you can deduce their x position knowing the width of the graph container, the y value is the slider current value + some correction with the slider button size.